# Add elements from array to array onload

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a type of quiz generator, and it works fine to by "onclick" add questions and answers, but if I want to "load" these answers/questions from start. From for example an array. And when I change/save these answers/questions again, to push them into the same array.

Do you have any suggestions have to accomplish this? I succeded to load questions correct, like the code below. But Answers linked to the questions I found a bit more tricky.

I have a fiddle here with example: http://jsfiddle.net/j8h8x/2/

Here the code for loading questions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var q = new Question(count++, 'Question 1');
    questions.push(q);
});
```

There is a function on line 143 in the fiddle where the answers are created. (onclick not load)

Would appreciate any input!

Comment: this would make all the answers in a JavaScript array so it would be easy to get them all right, just open console and explorer the array.

Comment: do you just want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/j8h8x/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the `addAnswer` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var q = new Question(count++, 'Question 1');
    q.addAnswer('this is some text', 'hello', q);
    questions.push(q);
});
```